# Find final velocity of an object on an inclined plane without knowing the mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, mass, velocity

How do I find final velocity of an object on an inclined plane without knowing the mass of the object assuming that I have the degree, duration, and initial velocity? Without the mass, how can I solve a problem in this format?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is relevant, but is friction negligible?

Comment: yes, frictionless

Comment: Would you need to know the mass if the object was simply in free fall without air resistance in order to determine its velocity?

Comment: It is an object sliding down a hill with no fricition. The initial velocity is zero and I know the angle of the plane and how long it was sliding, but i dont know how fast its going when it reaches the bottom..

Comment: That's what Im trying to find

Comment: You need to know say either the height of the incline or the distance along the incline the object travelled, then just apply work kinetic energy theorem or you could just conserve energy from the point it started moving say at height 'h' to the bottom point of the incline since you said that there is no friction

Comment: Draw a free body diagram of the forces acting on the object, that should give you the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cosine of the incline times gravitational acceleration, $g$, will give you the forward acceleration force $a$ and

$$u + a \cdot t = v,$$

where $v$ is the final speed and $u$ is the initial speed. This analysis assumes no friction. If there is friction, you need to know the mass or the distance traveled in order to calculate the speed as a function of time.

The final velocity is obtained from

$$v =g \cdot \cos(\text{incline}) \cdot t + u$$

Comment: Im confused, i followed your steps but I cant solve my question. A sled starts from rest,
and slides down a 38.0
frictionless hill for 4.24 s.
How fast is it going at the end?

Comment: 38.0 degree hill

Comment: Its very easy, but I cant do it.

Comment: g is the gravitational constant. Use $g = 9.81$ in your calculation

Answer (score 0):

The mass isn't really relevant for gravitational acceleration (which is what you're looking at in an inclined plane, and neglecting friction). If you do the math, F = ma and so a = F/m; but for gravity F = GMm/r^2 and so the m's cancel out.

Put another way: all objects fall at the same rate in a uniform gravitational field and neglecting things like air resistance (or friction on an inclined plane).